# PrimeFaces menu not recognizing composite component inside a menu item

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a JSF/PrimeFaces project, and I'm encountering an issue with including a composite component inside a PrimeFaces menu item. The composite component is not being recognized, and I'm getting an error stating that the prefix for the composite component is not bound.

Here is an example of my code structure:

Main File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ez="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/ezcomp">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:form>
            <p:menubar>
                <p:menuitem>
                    <!-- Other menu item content -->
                </p:menuitem>
                <ez:pharmacyMenu /> <!-- Composite component usage -->
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Composite Component (ezcomp/pharmacyMenu.xhtml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <cc:implementation>

        <p:submenu styleClass="rightBordrOnly" label="Pharmacy" rendered="#{webUserController.hasPrivilege('Pharmacy')}">
            <!-- Submenu content -->
        </p:submenu>

    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

The ez:pharmacyMenu composite component is located in a separate file named ezcomp/pharmacyMenu.xhtml under the resources folder, and it has the correct namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:ez="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/ezcomp"
```

However, when I try to run the application, I receive the following error:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing
> /resources/ezcomp/pharmacyMenu.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 160] The
> prefix "ez" for element "ez:pharmacyMenu" is not bound.

Line No 160 is this

```
<ez:pharmacyMenu/>
```

I have double-checked the placement and naming of the composite component file, as well as the namespace declaration in the main file. Everything seems to be in order.

Is it possible to include a composite component inside a PrimeFaces menu item? If so, what could be causing this error? Are there any additional steps or configurations that I need to consider?

I appreciate any guidance or insights on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently added to PrimeFaces 13.0.0-RC1 or higher with this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4738

A new "custom" facet was added so if you want to completely control the contents of a menu item you can do this...

```xml
<p:menuitem>
   <f:facet name="custom">
       <h:link outcome="NewPage" value="My Custom Link"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:menuitem>
```